# Jupyter kernel keeps crashing -- "No module named prompt_toolkit.formatted_text"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I cannot get Jupyter Notebook running -- it keeps restarting the kernel and giving the error message,

```
ImportError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'
```

A few threads online say it is an issue with ipython versioning which can be fixed by a rollback, but that hasn't worked for me.

Here are my current versions of relevant packages:

- conda==4.5.11
- ipykernel==4.10.0
- ipython==6.5.0
- ipython-genutils==0.2.0
- ipywidgets==7.4.2
- jupyter==1.0.0
- jupyter-client==5.2.3
- jupyter-console==4.1.1
- jupyter-core==4.4.0
- jupyter-kernel-gateway==2.1.0
- jupyterlab==0.34.12
- jupyterlab-launcher==0.13.1
- notebook==5.7.0
- prompt-toolkit==1.0.15

Any help you can provide would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did have the same issue with Jupyter Notebook. Point is that `ipython` requirement specific version of `prompt-toolkit`. In my case, I have `ipython` 7.2.0 which required `prompt-toolkit` <2.1.0,>=2.0.0

I just added `prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0` to my requirements.txt to solve this problem.

Try to run `pip install prompt_toolkit` and see which version of `prompt_toolkit` need in your project.

Comment: Which requirements.txt are you talking about?